# Data type conversion when (JNI) calling a function from cpp lib

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

CPP noob here. I am trying to call a library function from my java app. Need help in matching the data types for C function in my java class

C function signature

```
#define I_REAL double

int myfunction(int size,
  I_REAL const *const *inputs,
  I_REAL const *options,
  I_REAL *const *outputs);
```

My java native method signature (this might be incorrect, I was not exactly sure how  `const *const *inputs` will translate in java)

```
    public static native int myfunction(int size,
                                final double[][] inputs,
                                final double[] options,
                                final double[][] outputs);
```

Then I generate the header file using `javac Myclass.java -h .`

Then I implementation of my cpp code -

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_raj_myfunction
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jobjectArray, jdoubleArray, jobjectArray)
 {
  // something useful here
 }
```

I get a runtime error - `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.raj.Myclass.myfunction(I[D[D[D)I`

I'm thinking that my java native method signature is having some problem. I has to match the C function signature, any help is appreciated.

Comment: On the face of it, your runtime exception is correct. The native method signature is different. But usually such problems are detected by Java compiler earlier. Are you calling the native method through reflection? Or from C++ via JNI? Please share the snippet where you call **com.raj.Myclass.myfunction**.

Comment: I don't think this is right. "[D[D[D" suggests three arrays of doubles, and Raj expects "[[D[D[[D" if I'm not wrong. This question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96947/jni-multidimensional-array-as-return-value contains similar construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 2 things here:

- double[][] to double[]
- add casting with `reinterpret_cast`

so in your jni function call you must do -
`reinterpret_cast<I_REAL const *const*>(&inputs)` where you are calling your C function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from `jdouble* incoming` directly like reading from a `double` array.